# creating a proportion column with two decimal places

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two existing columns and have created a new blank column.

```
Column1   Column2   NewColumn
A            B        A/B

C            D        C/D
```

When I try the following my NewColumn is populated with 1's and 0's.  I would like a decimal representation of the proportion.

```
update MyTable
set NewColumnd = ((Column1/Column2)*1.00)
where Column2 != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You're performing the conversion too late - the division has already been performed using integer math, and than the conversion to float occurs. Maybe try:

```
update MyTable
set NewColumnd = ((Column1*1.00)/Column2)
where Column2 != 0
```

Although it should be noted that, if the formula should always hold, a computed column would be better than something produced via an `UPDATE`.

Comment: still no luck when using an earlier conversion. I defined NewColumn as numeric and column1 and column2 are both numeric

Comment: @user2448666 - the default scale for numeric columns is `0` (i.e. no decimal places) although I'd have thought that the general math rules should produce a decimal result if required. Can you create a small but complete example that exhibits the problem and edit it into you question?

Comment: Per the last comment I changed my approach and now have used

Comment: column1   column2    NewColumn
20.00 64.69 0
30.00 300.00 1
35.00 448.45 0
0.00 35.00 0

Comment: @user2448666 - if you want to give some example data (and hopefully expected results), please use the edit link below your question. And note that the `{}` button can help with code formatting and make things readable.